# access current ng-repeat element from nested html element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm new to angular currently trying to complete the 'ng-book' textbook.

I am using ng-repeat to filter a list of people that match the search criteria.  I have the filter working as I desire.  I'm having difficulty accessing the current ng-repeat element from an html element that is nested in the html element that ng-repeat controls.

For example run the snippet and search for 'pizza'.  It lists the 3 people who like pizza.  But for each person, I want to print the rest of their attributes in a nested `<dd>` element. But I looks as if I don't have access to the ng-repeat element there, as nothing displays.  I would also like this element to be repeated and correspond to each `<dt>` element.

I am more interested in what the 'angular' way of doing this is.
Thanks for reading!

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("SearchController", function($scope) {
  $scope.search = {};

  $scope.search.people = [{
      name: 'Stephen',
      food: ['pizza', 'ice cream'],
      hobbies: ['programming', 'hiking', 'traveling'],
      location: 'austin'
    },
    {
      name: 'Sara',
      food: ['cheese', 'bacon', 'cupcakes'],
      hobbies: ['hiking', 'swimming', 'bars'],
      location: 'san antonio'
    },
    {
      name: 'jaqueline',
      food: ['pizza', 'hot cheetos', 'pasta', 'tacos'],
      hobbies: ['softball', 'dance', 'music', 'vinyls', 'makeup'],
      location: 'san francisco'
    },
    {
      name: 'Jake',
      food: ['burgers', 'bbq', 'chinese'],
      hobbies: ['running', 'bars', 'traveling'],
      location: 'washingtion d.c.'
    },
    {
      name: 'Chris',
      food: ['chinese', 'sandwiches', 'burgers'],
      hobbies: ['programming', 'traveling', 'hacking'],
      location: 'maryland'
    },
    {
      name: 'Lisa',
      food: ['donuts', 'sandwiches', 'bbq', 'pizza'],
      hobbies: ['working out', 'running', 'traveling', 'dancing'],
      location: 'new jersey'
    }
  ];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="SearchController">
    <input ng-model="search.query" type="text">
    <dl>
      <dt ng-repeat="person in search.people | filter:search.query">
        {{ person.name }}
        <dd>
          - likes {{ person.food }}, {{ person.hobbies }}
          <br>
          -lives in {{ person.location }}
        </dd>

      </dt>
    </dl>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there's nothing wrong with your angular, it's just that DD can't have nested DT, see examples how it should be used: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_dd.asp). With your code, I guess it should be something like that:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("SearchController", function($scope) {
  $scope.search = {};

  $scope.search.people = [{
      name: 'Stephen',
      food: ['pizza', 'ice cream'],
      hobbies: ['programming', 'hiking', 'traveling'],
      location: 'austin'
    },
    {
      name: 'Sara',
      food: ['cheese', 'bacon', 'cupcakes'],
      hobbies: ['hiking', 'swimming', 'bars'],
      location: 'san antonio'
    },
    {
      name: 'jaqueline',
      food: ['pizza', 'hot cheetos', 'pasta', 'tacos'],
      hobbies: ['softball', 'dance', 'music', 'vinyls', 'makeup'],
      location: 'san francisco'
    },
    {
      name: 'Jake',
      food: ['burgers', 'bbq', 'chinese'],
      hobbies: ['running', 'bars', 'traveling'],
      location: 'washingtion d.c.'
    },
    {
      name: 'Chris',
      food: ['chinese', 'sandwiches', 'burgers'],
      hobbies: ['programming', 'traveling', 'hacking'],
      location: 'maryland'
    },
    {
      name: 'Lisa',
      food: ['donuts', 'sandwiches', 'bbq', 'pizza'],
      hobbies: ['working out', 'running', 'traveling', 'dancing'],
      location: 'new jersey'
    }
  ];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="SearchController">
    <input ng-model="search.query" type="text">
    <dl>
      <div ng-repeat="person in search.people | filter:search.query">
        {{ person.name }}
        
          <dt>likes</dt> <dd>{{ person.food }}, {{ person.hobbies }}</dd>
          <br>
          <dt>lives in</dt> <dd>{{ person.location }}</dd>

      </div>
    </dl>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Michal!  Like you did in your code I needed to put the ng-repeat in a <div> that wrapped around the <dt> and <dd> elements.  And yes I was nesting <dd> in the <dt> when I shouldn't have.  Appreciate the help!